# Excel IF AND OR condition together

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to use this formula in excel but am getting an error. Can someone please help?

=IF(OR(AND(B2>=Sheet3!$B$4,B2<=Sheet3!$C$4),AND(B2>=Sheet3!B6,B2<=Sheet3!C6))),"Blue","Grey")

Programmatically, I am trying to get this:

```
If((a>x && a<y) || (a>x1 && a<y1)){
           Blue
           }
   else
           {
           Grey
           }
```

Comment: What's the error? BTW, you won't be able to replicate the short-circuit logic operators `||` and `&&` in Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parenthesis are unbalanced. Try:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2>=Sheet3!$B$4,B2<=Sheet3!$C$4),AND(B2>=Sheet3!B6,B2<=Sheet3!C6)),"Blue","Grey")
```